# NGINX upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I'm usinng nginx to deploy laravel project. So, it's the first time that I write nginx configuration for php.

This is my configuration. I am getting 502 Bad Gateway with upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client error.

*/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/teleport.conf*

```
 server {


  listen 443 ssl default_server;
  listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

  include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

 root /home/user/teleport/TeleportApi/public;


 index index.php;

 server_name bestexpress.uz;

 location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
 }


 location ~ \.php$ {
  include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

  fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8443;
 }

 location ~ /\.ht {
  deny all;
 }




server {
    if ($host = bestexpress.uz) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


 listen 80;
 listen [::]:80;

 server_name bestexpress.uz;

 root /home/user/teleport/TeleportApi/public;
 index index.php;

 location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
 }


}
```

*Error:*

```
upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream,
```

Comment: are you trying to proxy that IP that didn't exist yet?